# Animate 24 large images - each of 728x936 size

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, ios5, timer

I have them animating right now by setting the content of the layer of a UIImageView.
I have also tried setting the image property of UIImageView with:

```
self.curtainAnimationView.image = image;
```

I am using an NSTimer to call a method that sets the image:

```
- (void) performCurtainAnimationWithFrame {    
    NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    CGImageRef ref = ((UIImage *)[animationImages objectAtIndex:currentFrame]).CGImage;    
    self.curtainAnimationView.layer.contents = (id)ref;
    CGImageRelease(ref);
    [pool drain];

    currentFrame++;
}
```

The timer function is:

```
NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(performCurtainAnimationWithFrame) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

It is an iPad project thus the large image sizes.

I have also used the animationImages property of a UIImageView, but I need to know when the animation ends for which there is no delegate method in UIImageView.

If anyone has any input, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How about animating from an array

```
yourImageView.animationImages=arrayOfImages;
yourImageView.animationDuration=5.0;
yourImageView.animationRepeatCount=1;

[yourImageView startAnimating];
```

Then you know the duration so

```
[self performSelector:@selector(yourMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

Comment: As I said I have already tried the animationImages property of UIImageView. Because of the size of images, there is no guarantee that the animation will end at 5 seconds, and besides, I want to animate it in 1 second, and it definitely takes longer than that.

Answer (score 1):

This may seem a bit glib, but why not make it into a video and just play that? The delegate will let you know when it has finished playing.

Comment: That is because I am playing a video right after the animation has finished playing. The animation I am using, acts as the curtain opening. I have tried that rout of playing one video before another, but it looks really bad on the original iPad - in terms of there is a log at the beginning of the animation video, and also video's do not have any transparencies.

Comment: Ahh I see, hmm if the curtain itself is not rippling or otherwise animating you could just use one or two images in a CALayer and animate the layer. If the curtain is moving, try CAKeyframeAnimation and animate the contents with CGIImageRefs (keeping the layers opaque will help too). You could also try creating an array CALayers (and call display) beforehand and using the prerendered CALayer.content for the CAKeyframeAnimation content animation.